# Can I ride Odahviing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

The Dragonborn DLC allows you to learn the "Bend Will" shout, which will let you soar about on a Dragon (sidenote: wheeeee!). Does this only work on generic, unnamed dragons?

I assume Alduin is unavailible, but I'd like to be able to ride a dragon anywhere - ideally, I could use Call Dragon to bring Odahviing, and then Bend Will to ride him. Does this work, or am I limited to the nameless ones?

Comment: You'd have to wait for 5 minutes before you could ride Oda.

Comment: @kotekzot It's possible to reset your shout CDs via console, items, etc.

Comment: Wait, what items reset your shout cooldown?

Comment: @kotekzot reduce it.

Comment: Weee Yes you can. And it is awsome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bend Will can be used on Odahviing and he can be ridden.

[image: Taken from Imgur]
Picture from https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5vMk.jpg